# NodeJS render a view from AJAX call

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, post

I trying to render a view using an AJAX call:

```
let data = {}
data.ph_user = ph_user 
data.nav_destination ='bids_review'
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/users/navigation',

});
```

The router's code is:

```
router.post('/navigation', (req, res) => {
 try {
  var fname = req.body['ph_user']
  var main_block = req.body['nav_destination']
    if(main_block='bids_review'){
     console.log(fname, main_block, 'zzzz')
     res.render('bids_review', {ph_user: fname, main_block: 'dashboard'});
    } 
   }catch(err){
     console.log(err)
  }  
 })
```

It looks like route is called properly but new view is not rendered. I don't get any errors on either server or client side. 
I know i can do via form but would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this with AJAX call. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route returns rendered HTML to the AJAX call. If you want to render HTML directly from the server, do not use AJAX, just redirect to the route (i.e. use a form to post the data, or change the route to `.get` and redirect to the location).

To keep using AJAX, you probably want to return JSON from the route, and render it on the client.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: I changed the AJAX call to GET and using res.redirect('bid_review'). Now I am getting an errror on the client side: GET http://localhost:3000/users/bids_review 404 (Not Found).  I have bid_review.ejs file in Views folder of my Express project

Comment: Again: if you want to use AJAX, return JSON from the route, and render on the client. If you want to use server-side render, redirect the client to the route (use a form to post to the route, or `location.href=<my route>` on the client side).

Comment: Got it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did an Ajax call for modifying data. After the update the partial page had to be displayed again but now with information that the data has been updated. The code is just sample code but the important part is in the `response` the response.body is a stream. If you stream that to the partial (innerHTML), then your page is updated with the `res.render` data. Extra note: you could put that code in a separate function and then you could work with PUG with partials too :-)

```
// get form data, save history and post data to database
await this.serializeForm(form)
  .then(data => 
    this.replaceState(form.action).then( () => 
      fetch(form.action, { 
        method: "POST", 
        headers: { 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          "Content-Type": "application/json" },            
        body: JSON.stringify(data) 
      }).then( (response) => 
          response
            .body
            .getReader()
            .read()
            .then( ({value}) => {
              let html = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(value);              
              this.partialPage.innerHTML = html;
            })
      )));
```